# RAID 5 won't mount

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm, raid5

I have a qnap NAS which is running a version of ubuntu and I'm not getting any help from their forum so I thought I'd ask my question here.

I "had" 3 2TB HD's in a raid 5 configuration.  When I got back from my holiday vacation, I found that the raid volume wasn't mounted.  I ran SMART utility from the QNAP admin page and it detected read errors on Disk2 so I bought another 2TB disk, did a swap and it looked like it was going to fix my problem:

```
[~] # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath]
md0 : active raid5 sdd3[3] sdc3[2] sda3[0]
      3903891200 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [U_U]
      [========>............]  recovery = 41.1% (802441984/1951945600) finish=285.7min speed=67047K/sec
```

I went to bed and let it finish rebuilding.  The next morning I tried to create the array and it failed:

```
[~] # mdadm -CfR --assume-clean /dev/md0 -l 5 -n 3 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdc3
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
    size=-391076224K  mtime=Thu Jan  2 03:30:10 2014
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid5 devices=3 ctime=Tue Jan  7 10:01:03 2014
mdadm: /dev/sda3 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
    size=-403668988K  mtime=Sat Jan 15 17:45:38 2011
mdadm: /dev/sda3 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid5 devices=3 ctime=Tue Jan  7 10:01:03 2014
mdadm: /dev/sdc3 appears to be part of a raid array:
    level=raid5 devices=3 ctime=Tue Jan  7 10:01:03 2014
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.

[~] # mount /dev/md0 /share/MD0_DATA -t ext4
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

[~] # dmesg | tail
[ 5474.498500] EXT4-fs (md0): ext4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 1952 not in group (block 224078240)!
[ 5474.504503] EXT4-fs (md0): group descriptors corrupted!
```

I ran e2fsck and it complained about the superblock:

```
[~] # e2fsck -f /dev/md0
e2fsck 1.41.4 (27-Jan-2009)
e2fsck: Group descriptors look bad... trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Filesystem revision too high while trying to open /dev/md0
The filesystem revision is apparently too high for this version of e2fsck.
(Or the filesystem superblock is corrupt)


The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

I tried alternate superblocks:

```
[~] # dumpe2fs /dev/md0 | grep -i superblock
dumpe2fs 1.41.4 (27-Jan-2009)
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-233
  Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-33001
  Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98537
  Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-164073
...
```

When I tried the 2nd value, it spit out all sorts of errors, here's a snippit of them:

```
[~] # e2fsck -b 98304 /dev/md0
e2fsck 1.41.4 (27-Jan-2009)
Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
answer=1
*** ext3 journal has been deleted - filesystem is now ext2 only ***

Block bitmap for group 1920 is not in group.  (block 223029632)
answer=1
Inode bitmap for group 1920 is not in group.  (block 971776033)
answer=1
Inode table for group 1920 is not in group.  (block 63045632)
WARNING: SEVERE DATA LOSS POSSIBLE.
answer=1
Group descriptor 1920 marked uninitialized without feature set.
answer=1
Block bitmap for group 1921 is not in group.  (block 62916993)
answer=1
Inode bitmap for group 1921 is not in group.  (block 62916994)
answer=1
Group descriptor 1921 marked uninitialized without feature set.
answer=1
Block bitmap for group 1922 is not in group.  (block 1236358788)
answer=1
Group descriptor 1922 marked uninitialized without feature set.
answer=1
Inode table for group 1923 is not in group.  (block 2996300427)
WARNING: SEVERE DATA LOSS POSSIBLE.
...
Resize inode not valid.  answer=1
/dev/md0 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Root inode is not a directory.  answer=1
Inode 241 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
answer=1
Inode 263, i_blocks is 139224, should be 139056.  answer=1
Inode 264 has illegal block(s).  answer=1
Illegal block #2060 (2770694604) in inode 264.  answer=1
CLEARED.
Illegal block #2061 (2431456604) in inode 264.  answer=1
CLEARED.
...
Too many illegal blocks in inode 264.
answer=1
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  answer=1
Inode 8433 was part of the orphaned inode list.  answer=1
FIXED.
Inode 8433 has imagic flag set.  answer=1
Inode 8433 has a extra size (48936) which is invalid
answer=1
Inode 8434 was part of the orphaned inode list.  answer=1
FIXED.
Inode 8434 has imagic flag set.  answer=1
Inode 8434 has a extra size (49000) which is invalid
...
Inode 16369 is in use, but has dtime set.  answer=1
Inode 16369 has a extra size (35995) which is invalid
answer=1
Inode 16370 is in use, but has dtime set.  answer=1
Inode 16370 has imagic flag set.  answer=1
Inode 16370 has a extra size (26087) which is invalid
answer=1
Inode 16371 is in use, but has dtime set.  answer=1
Inode 16371 has imagic flag set.  answer=1
Inode 16371 has a extra size (1476) which is invalid
answer=1
Inode 16372 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
...
Inode 16380 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
answer=1
Inode 16381 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
answer=1
Inode 16382 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
answer=1
Inode 16383 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
answer=1
Inode 16384 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
answer=1
Inode 16375 has compression flag set on filesystem without compression support.  answer=1
Inode 16375 has a bad extended attribute block 335544554.  answer=1
Inode 16375 has INDEX_FL flag set but is not a directory.
answer=1
Inode 16375, i_size is 4795354609508463505, should be 0.  answer=1
Inode 16375, i_blocks is 119976829646520, should be 0.  answer=1
Inode 16373 has compression flag set on filesystem without compression support.  answer=1
...
Inode 49141 is in use, but has dtime set.  answer=1
Inode 49141 has a extra size (53130) which is invalid
answer=1
Inode 49142 is in use, but has dtime set.  answer=1
Inode 49142 has a extra size (15011) which is invalid
answer=1
Inode 49143 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
answer=1
Inode 49144 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
...
```

I finally did a ctrl-C to stop it, afraid it was going to cause more problems. It then spit out this:

```
^CRecreate journalanswer=1
Creating journal (32768 blocks): 

 Done.

*** journal has been re-created - filesystem is now ext3 again ***
/dev/md0: e2fsck canceled.

/dev/md0: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
[~] #
```

Any help on what to try next would be appreciated.  I did have a couple questions about raid's and mdadm since I'm a newbie when it comes to them.

1. what happens if you try to mount them out of order, ie

   mdadm -CfR --assume-clean /dev/md0 -l 5 -n 3 /dev/**sda3** /dev/**sdb3** /dev/sdc3

   instead of

   mdadm -CfR --assume-clean /dev/md0 -l 5 -n 3 /dev/**sdb3** /dev/**sda3** /dev/sdc3
2. and why, when I run the mdadm command, is my new drive "sdb3" the only one showing the message: *appears to contain an ext2fs file system*?  Could that be part of my problem?

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array, like formatting a partition, is destructive; you don't do that where you already have unless you want to wipe it out and start over.

Since you did --assume-clean, hopefully not too much damage has been done.  You probably got the order of the disks wrong when you recreated the array, so you will need to try again with the correct order.